# webservices vs RMI/RPC

Tags: web-services, terminology

Does anyone knows the difference between a webservice and RPC/RMI ?

Comment: Have you tried finding out by reading about them?

Comment: If you do your homework, you'll know too.

Comment: well i read about them. for me they all look the same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"webservice" is a generic term for a remote service accessed programmatically, although it usually is used to refer to a SOAP web service, e.g. SOAP XML messages passed via HTTP.

RPC (Remote Procedure Call)  is a rather old-fashioned term for invoking a service remotely. The term isn't used much any more.

RMI is a specific Java technology for invoking methods on remote objects. It's java only, and uses a binary wire protocol (JRMP).

Comment: don't they all perform the same service ? whats the main reason to give a new name webservices ?

Comment: @user602774: They all more or less do the same thing, but in different ways. It's a fashion thing, for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

RPC (Remote Procedure Call) is a type of remote invocation that includes RMI (Remote Method Invocation) and RRP (Request-Reply Protocol)- a good example of RRP is HTTP protocol;

All of them are different types (paradigms) of communication between components of distributed systems (i.e. different machines). In simple words, RPC is basically calling a procedure (function if you will) on a remote machine as if it is done on a local machine. It abstracts some important aspects of the distributing including marshaling.

Similarly, RMI is an extended RPC that goes into the world of distributed objects. It solves a lot of problems with OOP languages, but also there are a few things to consider (Parameter passing, Class call, etc). Of course, RMI is also referred commonly to the Java RMI, but as a concept it is not necessarily Java, it can be done in other languages, C++, C#;

Now a Web Service it's a way of interacting with servers in a more general way, in other words, it is a way of exposing some functionalities of a server on a web in a really nice and easy way to a lot of people. Usually, the interaction is done through Application Programming Interfaces (API), and the most common API paradigms are SOAP and REST. There are a lot of common and different things. But mainly, SOAP is a protocol, quite robust and standardized, REST is an architectural style, it is more lose and uses HTTP protocol and URI for its requests.